# Plotting the outer points on a scatter plot in Python

Tags: python, plot, graph

I would like to add a 'frontier' to the outer envelope of my scatter plot in Python.

How can I do this? One way, I imagine, would by fitting a curve to the outer envelope. But I'm not sure how to fit a curve only to the outer points, nor do I have an idea what such a model would be called.

Below are two images. To the left is my current scatter plot and to the right is an example of what I am after.

[image]

Comment: A place to start might be to calculate a rolling max of (n) points, and plot this along with the scatter.  (Difficult to test without having your dataset. I’ve simulated something similar (but inverse) and the rolling min has a decent fit.)